# Getting read_time on Firestore document snapshot

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The documentation here: https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html?highlight=exists#google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentSnapshot
says that it is possible to get the read_time of the DocumentSnapshot

I read my database like so:

```
ref = db_name.document(userid)
uid = ref.get()
if uid.exists:
    read_time = uid.read_time
    print(read_time)
```

Prints out "None"

Why? The record does exist and can be operated on, but I need the read time.

Answer (score 1):

The API doc you linked says read_time is a **parameter** to the DocumentSnapshot constructor.  It's not a property.  That said, it's not clear to me why the constructor needs that value or how it's exposed.  It might be better to simply take a timestamp reading on your own, and not depend on what might be in the snapshot that isn't documented.

Comment: Yes, and the same documentation names "exists" also a parameter, though that one is widely used with no problems afaik. The doc also does mention that "Instances of this class are not intended to be constructed by hand, rather they'll be returned as responses to various methods"..

Comment: To be honest I just wanted a method to get current server time. Couldn't find anything more suitable and I don't really want to do something like first write SERVER_TIMESTAMP and then read it just for that.. is there no other way with firestore?

Comment: There is no other way.